# neo4j - traversing structure to build XML

Tags: algorithm, graph, neo4j, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

I have a neo4j graph of an organisation produced by active directory.

The only existing relation is MANAGE, Node 1 is the root node (top of organisation) and all other members eventually report to Node 1 via the MANAGE relationship.

I haven't touched Neo4j traversal, but I want to provide a comma-separated list of usernames and and produce a tree structure consisting of

Root Node <- children down to LCA and LCA <- children

I can already get the LCA in Neo4j, I just need to work out where to go from there.

```
        String users = "tom,sarah,liam";
    List<Node> nodeSet = new ArrayList<Node>();
    String usernames[] = users.split(",");
    for (String user : usernames) { 
        Node found = nodeIndex.get("username", user).getSingle();
        if (found != null) nodeSet.add(found);
    }

    Node lca = getLCA(nodeSet);

private Node getLCA(List<Node> nodes) { 
    RelationshipExpander expander = Traversal.expanderForTypes(RelTypes.MANAGE, Direction.INCOMING);

    return AncestorsUtil.lowestCommonAncestor(nodes, expander);
}
```

So if I provide the list "sarah,tom,liam" the following structure would be created:

```
          Root
           |
           | 
           |
           John
           |
           Jane
         /      \ 
   Sarah       Jerome
               /    \ 
             Liam    Tom
```

I would like to do this in XML or JSON like so: (XML Example below)

```
<user>
    <name>Root</name>
    <children>
        <user>
            <name>John</name>
            <children>
                <user>
                    <name>Jane</name>
                    <children>
                        <user>
                            <name>Sarah</name>
                        </user>
                        <user>
                            <name>Jerome</name>
                            <children>
                                        <user>
                                            <name>Liam</name>
                                        </user>
                                <user>
                                    <name>Tom</name>
                                </user>
                            </children>
                        </user>
                    </children>
                </user>
            </children>
        </user>
    </children>
</user>
```

Can someone point me in the right direction of where to start for this?

Comment: pls paste the part of your code/steps where you "get the LCA in Neo4j".

Comment: @ulkas I've pasted it above now.

Comment: I've created some Traversals which get root -> LCA and LCA -> each user but I'm unsure if I can write this as one traverser or how I would join the traversal results.

Answer (score 1):

Something like that: http://console.neo4j.org/r/canhtg

```
start n=node(0) 
match path=n-[:MANAGE*]-m 
with nodes(path) as nodes, length(path) as l 
return head(nodes), head(tail(nodes)),tail(tail(nodes)),l
```

What it does is:

- you match paths from your start node to arbitrary lengths, finally touching all nodes in your (sub)-graph
- you aggregate the nodes of the path into a collection named nodes
- you return the first, second, third etc. elements from that collection individually